# iPhone App Developement: deactivating incoming calls?

Tags: iphone

Hey guys,
is it possible to trigger the "airplane-mode" or deactivate all incoming calls within/inside an iPhone app?

Comment: This should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would hate any app that did this, and I would be angry if Apple let it on their store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no because Apple currently-provided SDK does not have published methods for doing this.

Comment: +1 That's OS-level stuff that is very appropriately kept entirely away from the app sandbox. It's possible through jailbreaking, but fortunately it's otherwise impossible.